# How to write full chat server / client using python 2.5

Tags: python, python-2.5

I want to write server/client chat protocol using python-2.5 .
I want to make protocol similar to yahoo messenger or google-talk.
Please suggest me how to start.

Thanks
Reetesh Nigam

Answer (score 3):

You should look at [Twisted Words](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWords).  Twisted is a Python networking library, and Words is a chat component for it.  It has support for XMPP/Jabber, the protocol used by Google Talk.

Comment: It also has support for IRC which may be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [xmppy](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/), though I'm sure `Twisted Words` (recommended by another answer) and [jabber.py](http://jabberpy.sourceforge.net/), [python-xmpp](https://launchpad.net/python-xmpp), and no doubt many others, are also usable.  Why not try them out a few of them and pick the one that best suits you?

Answer (score 0):

There are several popular Python libraries for working with XMPP, a/k/a the Jabber protocol, which Google Talk uses. Here is a [review that will point you to 3 of them](http://achievewith.us/public/articles/2008/08/11/python-and-jabber-head-to-head-library-review).

Comment: PyXMPP required Python 2.6 , but do not want to move into python 2.6.
So can you tell me some other libraries in which i can implement my chat server/client protocol using python 2.5

Comment: The other 2 mentioned in the article *do* work with Python 2.5.

For jabber.py version 0.5.0, download (http://sourceforge.net/projects/jabberpy/files/jabberpy%20libs/0.5/jabberpy-0.5-0.tar.gz/download), extract, and run `python setup.py`

For xmpp.py version 0.5.0-rc1, install from setup.py (http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmpppy/files/xmpppy/0.5.0-rc1/xmpppy-0.5.0rc1.tar.gz/download) or via easy-install (http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmpppy/files/xmpppy/0.5.0-rc1/xmpppy-0.5.0rc1-py2.5.egg/download)